# How to quickly check if specific keywords exist in a lot of log files in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, log-files, grep

I have run a program that writes a lot of log files in a lot of directories.
For example, there are hundreds directories, and every one includes thousands of log files.
I need to find out the files those include the keywords "**WARNN**", "**ERROR**" and "**FATAL**" in command-line shell.
I tried to use "grep WARRN */*", but I got "-bash: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long".

Would any good man please tell me a method?
Any reply or hint will be much aprreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to apply grep on the results of find, for example:

```
find . -type f -print | xargs grep WARNN
```

To know which file matches use option `-n` of grep